# String array reverse without using string function

Tags: java, arrays, string

This code is showing `null` as an output . Please tell me which part of my code is going to be wrong ?

```
public class Compre {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a="abcefgh";
        String ar[]=a.split("");
        String arr[]=new String[100];
        int j=0;
        for(int i=a.length()-1;i<0;--i){
            arr[j]=ar[i];
        }
        ++j;
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please tell us what you want to do.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Why is the array initialized to a size of 100? Indent your code and you'll notice that ++j probably should be at a different place.

Comment: `i<0` should be `i >= 0`.

Comment: What's the point of `arr`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is inside for loop, change it to:

```
for(int i=a.length()-1;i>=0;--i){
        arr[j++]=ar[i];
    }
```

And then in `arr` you have reversed a. But trying to print out `arr[j]` is pointless because it have to be `null` because you just increment `j` at last index of your `string`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your code, I will describe all of them:

1. there is no need to use `split` method, you can use `charAt` method instead in this problem
2. you assumed the `length` of ar is at most `100` ? if i enter `a` with length `101` or longer size your program gonna **fail** , you can use following method instead :

   ```
   String arr[]=new String[a.length];
   ```
3. there is no need the arr be `String` because the `String` itself is an `array` of `char` characters , so you can use this code instead :

   ```
   char arr[]=new char[a.length];
   ```
4. your loops `condition` is **wrong** at first , becuase the length of `"abcdefg"` is equal to `7` , but you said `i<0` , it is **not** `true` , so the loop is not gonna started , you can rewrite `i>=0` in the condition instead :

   ```
   for(int i=a.length()-1;i>=0;--i)
   ```
5. you have to increment the value of `j` inside the loop , not outside of that :

   ```
   int j=0;
   for(int i=a.length()-1;i>=0;--i)
   {
     arr[j]=ar.charAt(i);
     ++j;
   }
   ```

or use this **equal** one instead , I *prefer* to use this :

```
int j=0;
for(int i=a.length()-1;i>=0;--i)
  arr[j++]=ar.charAt(i);
```

then print your reversed array :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Your problem is that you never enter the loop.

You initialize i to `a.length()-1` which is 6. And then, your **for loop condition** is when `i<0`; This way, you never put any values to arr and `arr[j]` is `null` because it is not initialized.

**Second:** `++j` should be inside the loop.

**Third:** when you print the values in the end, you should print arr[--j] (the last value).

**Fixed code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a="abcefgh";

    String ar[]=a.split("");
    String arr[]=new String[100];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=a.length()-1; i>=0 ;--i){ // Your problem is here
        arr[j]=ar[i];
        ++j; // And here
    }
    System.out.println(arr[--j]); // And here
```

}

This should work fine.

Comment: @himanshu try the fixed code.

Comment: it working fine ty

Comment: @himanshu did you understand what was wrong? :)

Comment: good answer +1 , try using numeric index for more clarity

Comment: @OferArial ty for suggestion